# Any way to see where python is importing a module from?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

So I installed the facebook module, realized it was the wrong one, used pip to uninstall and then installed facebook-sdk. Here is my code:

```
import facebook

token = '[token]'

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
profile = graph.get_object("me")
friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")

friend_list = [friend['name'] for friend in friends['data']]

print friend_list
```

and get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mgraves\Desktop\facebook.py", line 1, in <module>
    import facebook
  File "C:\Users\mgraves\Desktop\facebook.py", line 5, in <module>
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GraphAPI'
```

When looking this up, EVERY result says to uninstall facebook and facebook-sdk and reinstall facebook-sdk. And I have, many many times. I searched /python27/ for facebook afterwards to make sure the files were gone.

Is there any way on a windows machine to trace back where I am importing "facebook" from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module objects have a `__file__` attribute, and the object representation also includes the file:

```
print facebook
print facebook.__file__
```

In your case, you are importing *your own script*; you named it `facebook` as well and are masking the installed module:

```
  File "C:\Users\mgraves\Desktop\facebook.py", line 1, in <module>
    import facebook
  File "C:\Users\mgraves\Desktop\facebook.py", line 5, in <module>
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
```

Note the filename in the first line, then the fact that the *same file* is used for that import. Python stores the main script as `__main__`, so importing the script itself results in another module being created for the actual filename.

Comment: Usually I would lie and say I found the file that was messing it up, but holy crap. How did I make the mistake of naming my python script "facebook.py"?

Thank you for pointing that out to me, and thanks for the help. I'm sure that will come in handy in the future.